# How to randomly spawn objects a limited distance from another object?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I have a cube 'static' with a collision sensor to my character, and near that cube there should spawn in nearby distances, but random, another cube.

When the player walks against the other cube there should happen the same thing.

How do I write this in python?